# Is this answer is a good review audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-answer, specific-audit

I encountered [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/30482214) for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70000547/10952503) a few days ago.

The answer is pretty short. There isn't any explanation of what the issue is, and why the answer can fix it. Just a "try set this". No documentation linked.

As asked in a comment, I was thinking about an answer like that:

> Since SDK X this have been added with some feature .
>
> You should use SDK X by set target & compile as X or newer

So, for me, it was an answer that requires more details, so, I clicked "Share feedback". I failed this audit and, as a result, am suspended from reviewing.

As I didn't want to leave this answer like that, I made an edit then added a comment (after review).

Is this a good audit?

Comment: What else would you have added to the answer? Because for me it seems as if the answer states everything needed to solve the problem? The problem is that a certain feature is only available starting from a specific version and the answer states the minimal version needed to solve the problem.

Comment: Something like "*Since X SDK this have been added <link to doc>. You should use SQK X by set target & compile as X or newer <possible link to doc for gradle config>*", something that can be more precise and can be applied to other feature. Now, is that 31 the lower version required ? Why this version precisly ?

Comment: Also: People downvote the answer (was at 15, now at 12) but also people downvote my question. So the answer is bad, but the audit is good ? What does that means ?

Comment: I think the discussion if it's a good audit is rather useless: Audits are automatically picked from posts the system thinks are good. In this case, 15 upvotes, no downvotes -> system thinks that it's good. How else would the system identify good posts unless by looking at the voting?

Comment: @BDL At the beginning I was asking if it was a good reaction/good reason to be review-banned. I know they are choosed automatically, I'm here mostly to know if I made the good think and if yes, if I can be unbanned

Comment: This is just a case you'll have to learn from. Often small answers like that pointing out a bugfix or version-related issue get heavily upvoted because a lot of people all of a sudden had this problem due to an update. When you see cases like this, it's best to visit the post and see what's up before acting on the review.

Comment: @Elikill58 "if I can be unbanned" - keep in mind you would be going back to a state where you are one failed audit away from being banned again. Does having that knowledge sound appealing to you? It doesn't to me, I'd rather just eat the ban I have and afterwards be cautiously optimistic that it is never going to catch me ever again.

Comment: @Elikill58 Given the feedback you've received here and your concern and general review history - I've reset the review suspension period to 2 days and unsuspended you from review. Just be wary of things like this in the future. Thanks!

Comment: KevinB: Yes, and I think I will make a proposal to never have review audit for good post (such as Suggested edit review queue).. @Gimby Yes, I know. If mod think I'm wrongly banned, why wait until full ban time ? I will just make more attention about those types of post which have upvote instead they are not so good.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your feedback.

The moderator [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) added [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413599/?noredirect=1#comment883597_413599) because he accepted my question, and unbanned me!