# Edited questions should not be used as review audits in Close Review queue

Tags: support, bug, status-review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just encoutered [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/34252455) that I failed. The concerned post is [I can not connect my api with the oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75990521/i-can-not-connect-my-api-with-the-oracle-database).

When reviewing, I saw everything I'm looking for:

- **A clear issue**: There are error logs
- **Useful information** with the `pom.xml` for oracle library versions used
- **The configuration** which is necessary with this type of issue
- **Some explanation** as begin and end, about what he does, when the issue appears etc
- **Code formatted** so it's easy to read, maybe we can edit for some lower case or quick detail, but in general the post is well formatted/readable

I clicked on Leave open, but I failed. When doing this post and searching for a reason about close votes, I saw **it has been edited after the post was closed**. So, it seems to be a bug, as what the audit showed is not what was closed.

Is that possible to see, when reviewing those types of audit, the version of the post before the edit, or simply don't automatically choose posts that were edited since the close vote?

Comment: As few mods comes here, can you remove it from my failed audit history? :)

Comment: No, audit results cannot be changed.

Comment: @SamuelLiew You can't reset it when it's not a ban? I know that [Jon Clements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413599/is-this-answer-is-a-good-review-audit#comment883597_413599) did it for me few years ago, I kept the audit failed but without the "bad part"

Comment: No, audit results cannot be changed by mods. Review suspensions can be lifted, but you are not review suspended.